# 2D Light Performance Optimization

Tags: c#, performance, xna, light

I'm currently trying to implement a simple 2D Lightning with XNA WITHOUT HLSL. The problem is, the way I'm doing it give me huge fps drops.

```
        //Create a new array to store the texture pixels.
        Color[] colorData = new Color[this.backgroundAtual.Texture.Height * this.backgroundAtual.Texture.Width];
        //I copy to the colorData a blackened copy of the original pixeldata
        Array.Copy(this.backgroundAtual.usingData, colorData, colorData.Length);

        //Create a rectangle to reduce the area of the texture where I have to make changes
        rec = new Rectangle((int)(l[0].Position.X - l[0].Radius), (int)(l[0].Position.Y - l[0].Radius), (int)(l[0].Radius * 2), (int)(l[0].Radius * 2));

        //Find the intersecting rectangle
        int x1 = Math.Max(rec.X, this.backgroundAtual.Texture.Bounds.X);
        int x2 = Math.Min(rec.X + rec.Width, this.backgroundAtual.Texture.Bounds.X + this.backgroundAtual.Texture.Bounds.Width);
        int y1 = Math.Max(rec.Y, this.backgroundAtual.Texture.Bounds.Y);
        int y2 = Math.Min(rec.Y + rec.Height, this.backgroundAtual.Texture.Bounds.Y + this.backgroundAtual.Texture.Bounds.Height);

        //Cycle through the rectangle on the texture
        for (int y = y1; y < y2; ++y)
        {
            for (int x = x1; x < x2; ++x)
            {
                pos = new Vector2(x, y);
                //Set the intensity of the color based on the distance from the center of the light
                colorData[(y * this.backgroundAtual.Texture.Width) + x] = colorData[(y * this.backgroundAtual.Texture.Width) + x] * ((l[0].Intensity / Vector2.Distance(l[0].Position, pos)) + 1);
            }
        }

        //Use setdata on the texture I'm going to draw so I can see the changes.
        this.backgroundAtual.Texture.SetData(colorData);
        //Draw the texture
        renderer.Draw(this.backgroundAtual.Texture, drawPosition, Color.White);
```

l[0] is the light. Is there any way to improve the speed of this process? If there isn't, is there any alternate way to implement lightning without HLSL? I'm currently using XNA. Sorry if my question wasn't clear. English is not my native language.

Thanks in advance

Comment: try to imagine how much this costs CPU time... looping over all pixels in some texture 60 times in second. to expensive. go with Partricks idea. or use shader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that there is a `GetData` call, maybe in your `usingData` property.  The `GetData` and `SetData` calls are pretty slow.  If these calls are in your main loop you are going to drop frames, especially if the textures are large.  In XNA when your create a `Texture2D` and call `Content.Load` on it, the `Texture2D`'s pixel data is stored in vram and moving that data back and forth to the cpu is a rather slow operation.

Without using HLSL, my best suggestion for 2D lights would be to create a `Texture2D` in the shape that you want the light to be, with the opacity getting lower towards the edges of the texture.  Render your scene to a `RenderTarget` then do another `SpriteBatch.Draw` with your lights using `Additive` blending.

Comment: Well it worked but I got another problem. I made it work but it doesn't look like a light. The method I was trying actually add some bright to my texture and this doesn't. Is this supposed to happen or I'm doing it wrong? Pic with the method you mentioned: http://s1073.photobucket.com/user/Celso_Shigaki/media/Youreffect_zps23c0afba.png.html?sort=3&o=0
Pic with the method I was using: http://s1073.photobucket.com/user/Celso_Shigaki/media/Myeffect_zps42f4c6c3.png.html?sort=3&o=1

Comment: If you are trying to get a more complex lighting effect, there is really no way to do it cpu side with a massive hit in frame rate.  Is there a reason that you don't want to use HLSL?  Shaders really are going to give you the power to create any kind of lighting effects you want.